# show the div when button clicked with css transition in asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a web application created in asp.net. In which, I would like to show a div (which is hidden initially) when a button is clicked with a css transition.

Additional Request:

The div that is shown on button click, will have some content added to it dynamically at run time.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

**Plain Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('BUTTON_ID').addEventListener('click', function(){ 
    document.getElementById('DIV_ID').style.display = 'block';
})
```

Alternatively, with **jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#BUTTON_ID').click(function(){ $('#DIV_ID').show() });
});
```

replace `BUTTON_ID` and `DIV_ID` with real element IDs.

**UPDATE:**

if you want the div to be shown with transition, i'd recommend to use `jQuery` as following:

```
$(function(){
    $('#BUTTON_ID').click(function(){ $('#DIV_ID').fadeIn() });
});
```

notice the `.fadeIn()` method, which can be replaced with `.show()`, `.slideDown()` and more. jQuery is fun.

**UPDATE 2:**

in order to inject dynamic content into the div, do as following:

```
$(function(){
    $('#BUTTON_ID').click(function(){ 
        $('#DIV_ID').html('<b>Hello, dynamic content!</b>');
        $('#DIV_ID').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

hope that helps.

Comment: I want the div to be displayed with some transition.

Comment: Apologize. I have updated my question with some additional request. Is that possible? If yes, How?

Comment: This is a .Net web application. Hence, the content is from backend. I tried your code. It works from frontend. Could you tell me how do I do from backend?

Comment: how about `$('#DIV_ID').html('<%=CONTENT_FROM_SERVER%>')`? (note that CONTENT_FROM_SERVER is a variable declared on server side)

Comment: Could you please explain me how?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation of the script from @geevee which I tend to use a lot, the DIV will slide up or down with a close and open option. Note the 500 is the speed of execution in milliseonds, you can change that to what ever suits you.

```
$(function(){
    $('#BUTTON_ID').click(function(){ 

            if ($('#DIV_ID').css('display') =='none')
            {
                $('#BUTTON_ID').html('Show DIV');
                $('#DIV_ID').slideDown(500); 

            }
            else
            {
                $('#BUTTON_ID').html('Hide DIV');
                $('#DIV_ID').slideUp(500); 
            }



    });//end .click
});//end onload
```

Hope this helps